# spark sql-providing a list parameter for sum function

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

im using spark dataframe API.
i'm trying to give sum() a list parameter containing columns names as strings.
when i'm putting columns names directly into the function- the script works'
when i'm trying to provide it to the function as a parameter of type list- i get the error:

```
"py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o155.sum.
: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String"
```

using same kind of list parameter for groupBy() is working.
this is my script:

```
groupBy_cols = ['date_expense_int', 'customer_id']
agged_cols_list = ['total_customer_exp_last_m','total_customer_exp_last_3m']

df = df.groupBy(groupBy_cols).sum(agged_cols_list)
```

when i write it like so it works:

```
df = df.groupBy(groupBy_cols).sum('total_customer_exp_last_m','total_customer_exp_last_3m')
```

i tryied also to give sum() a list of column by using

```
agged_cols_list2 = []
for i in agged_cols_list:
    agged_cols_list2.append(col(i))
```

also didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unpack your list using the asterisk notation:

```
df = df.groupBy(groupBy_cols).sum(*agged_cols_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are having a df like below and want to sum a list of fields

```
df.show(5,truncate=False)

+---+---------+----+
|id |subject  |mark|
+---+---------+----+
|100|English  |45  |
|100|Maths    |63  |
|100|Physics  |40  |
|100|Chemistry|94  |
|100|Biology  |74  |
+---+---------+----+

only showing top 5 rows

agged_cols_list=['subject', 'mark']

df.groupBy("id").agg(*[sum(col(c)) for c in agged_cols_list]).show(5,truncate=False)

+---+------------+---------+
|id |sum(subject)|sum(mark)|
+---+------------+---------+
|125|null        |330.0    |
|124|null        |332.0    |
|155|null        |304.0    |
|132|null        |382.0    |
|154|null        |300.0    |
+---+------------+---------+
```

Note that sum(subject) beomes null as it is a string column.
In this case you may want to apply count to subject and sum to mark. So you can use a dictionary

```
summary={ "subject":"count","mark":"sum" }

df.groupBy("id").agg(summary).show(5,truncate=False)

+---+--------------+---------+
|id |count(subject)|sum(mark)|
+---+--------------+---------+
|125|5             |330.0    |
|124|5             |332.0    |
|155|5             |304.0    |
|132|5             |382.0    |
|154|5             |300.0    |
+---+--------------+---------+
only showing top 5 rows
```